# Trying to Import background_thread from google.appengine.api (like in example) fails with ImportError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend, background-thread

Simply doing...

```
from google.appengine.api import background_thread
```

...like in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#background_threads), fails for me with...

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name background_thread
```

...when calling it from my backend.

How do I get this to import properly?

Comment: Are you using the Python 2.7 or Python 2.5 runtime?

Comment: Python 2.5... I understood from the [1.6.4. release-notes](http://googleappengine.blogspot.de/2012/03/app-engine-164-released.html) that this isn't Python 2.7 only?

Comment: Hmm; the documentation really doesn't seem to indicate that it's python2.7 only. On the other hand, your import works perfectly on shell-27.appspot.com and not on shell.appspot.com.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Python 2.7 only feature.  Also it's not supported in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It just works on Python 2.7 and it's not supported in the development server (as @Guido van Rossum says), just when you upload it on GAE servers